# Scaffold-DbContext generates wrong type

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, .net-6.0, scaffolding

I've got an .Net6 Web API project for which the model (database first) was generated via Scaffold-DbContext from an Oracle database. Oracle contains columns with `Number(4)` type which was generated to `byte` in the C# model. It seems that the generation looks into the table, saw that the values are less then 256 and decided that `byte` should fit. If now a number above 256 is entered in the table the query fails.

How can I force scaffold to use a bigger type in this case?

Answer (score 2):

In .NET 6 you can customize generated code with **Handlebars templates**. To do this you need to install the **EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Handlebars** NuGet package and then add Handlebars transformer.

After you install the NuGet package, you need to tell the `dotnet ef db scaffold` command to use the templates. You can do this by adding a class implementing `IDesignTimeServices` interface to your project. The interface has only one method to implement called `ConfigureDesignTimeServices`. In there you will register the Handlebars templates functionality.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace MyProject;

internal class MyDesignTimeService : IDesignTimeServices
{
    public void ConfigureDesignTimeServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddHandlebarsScaffolding();
    }
}
```

Now you can add HandlebarsTransformer and change the generated property type.

Let's say you want to do generate `int` instead of `byte` for only one column called **MyFourDigitsColumn**. You could do this by adding following transformer:

```
    serviceCollection.AddHandlebarsTransformers(
        propertyTransformer: p => p.PropertyName == "MyFourDigitsColumn"
            ? new EntityPropertyInfo("int", p.PropertyName, p.PropertyIsNullable)
            : p);
```

If you would like to do this for all types you can replace `byte` with `int` for all columns like this:

```
    serviceCollection.AddHandlebarsTransformers(
        propertyTransformer: p => p.PropertyType == "byte"
            ? new EntityPropertyInfo("int", p.PropertyName, p.PropertyIsNullable)
            : p);
```

When you now run the scaffolding now, you will notice that a new folder was created in you project called CodeTemplates and one config file.

[image: screenshot of CodeTemplates folder]

Now you can customize your generated entities and DbContext even more simply by changing the template and creating some Handlebars helpers.

For further information look at  https://github.com/TrackableEntities/EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Handlebars#handlebars-helpers-and-transformers

Comment: I added the class and the folders were generated but there is still the old type in the generation instead of the new one? Is the name of the class important? Must the class be in a certain folder? Is there an option where I can say which template should be used (didn't found any).

Comment: The name should not matter, neither the namespace. If the folders were generated, the DesignTimeService was found. Also make sure, that you register all the helpers and transformers at once, otherwise only the last one you add is used. (this should be called only once: `AddHandlebarsTransformers(propertyTransformer: yourTransformer)`).